# How to import data from text file into python's loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, csv

EDIT:

data from cosiek.txt:

```
time  20
speed 50
sth   30
car   new
```

I have a problem with importing data from my text (tab delimited) file to python script

I got:

`name,value = line.split("\t")`

`ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`

this is my code and picture of cosiek44.txt

[image]

```
variables = {}

with open("cosiek44.txt") as f:
     for i,line in enumerate(f):
        if i <=2:
            name,value = line.split("\t")
            variables[name] = float(value)
        else:
            name,value = line.split("\t")
            variables[name] = str(value)

a=variables["time"]
b=variables["speed"]
c=variables["sth"]
d=variables["new"]
```

Comment: Try again, start over and `print(line.split())` in the loop, then look at the output. Are you getting an empty list at the end?

Comment: By the way, using Pandas or at least the `csv` module would help you more

Comment: Use `f.readlines()`.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/in-python-how-do-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list

Comment: the list is empty

Comment: @Duraa Thet certainly won't happen with your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
with open('cosiek44.txt') as f:
    lines=f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line_content=lines.split()
        if line_content[-1].isdigit():
            variables[line_content[0]]=int(line_content[-1])
        else:
            variables[line_content[0]]=line_content[-1]
```

i dont know what you did wrong  except maybe there existing empty lines at the bottom of the file or some error in the line `for i,line in enumerate(f):`

Comment: empty lines - it was all about. 
Sometimes I'm really stupid :)

Comment: everyone makes mistakes :) they are a part of coding, please upvote my answer if it helped, thank you :)